# Jquery one function preventing checkboxes from working for other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below example, if I click a button to reset all my checkboxes. My next button that selects only certain ones will not work but It will work when I click it first. Any ideas?

```
$(function(){
   jQuery('.selectA-button').click(function(){
      $('.circle1L').addClass('circle-on');
      $('.circle2L').addClass('circle-on');
      $('.circle3L').addClass('circle-on');
      $('.circle4L').addClass('circle-on');
      $('.circle5L').addClass('circle-on');
      $('.circle6L').addClass('circle-on');
      $('input[name=onoffswitch1L]').attr('checked',true);
      $('input[name=onoffswitch2L]').attr('checked',true);
      $('input[name=onoffswitch3L]').attr('checked',true);
      $('input[name=onoffswitch4L]').attr('checked',true);
      $('input[name=onoffswitch5L]').attr('checked',true);
      $('input[name=onoffswitch6L]').attr('checked',true);
  });
$(function(){
  jQuery('.reset-button').click(function(){
       jQuery('.box-on').toggleClass('box-on');
       jQuery('.circle-on').toggleClass('circle-on');
       jQuery('.circle-on2').toggleClass('circle-on2');
       $('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

See this line:

```
$('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
```

use `.removeAttr` instead

https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

`checked="false"` will still contain the checked attribute

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp

Test with this:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="false"/>
```

Above markup shows a checked checkbox.

======================================================================

Edit: Actually better to use `prop('checked', true);` and .`prop('checked', false);`

See fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/dwrr3z35/6/

Comment: It would be better if you put the running code in a stack snippet instead of a remote fiddle.